# Photoshop Scripting: Hue Shifting

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I need to write a script to hue shift in photoshop.
What i need is to shift the hue of the foreground color and change its darkness and assign this functionality to a keystroke. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mins sharing your latest code?

Comment: Actually im starting to learn js and write the script but not sure if what i need is possible.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Change the foreground colour to HSV and shift the hue and modify the luminosity. If you're running the script from an action it'll increment the hue and darkness the same each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Hue Saturation Lightness shift:

```
function colourhsl(localRange, beginRamp, beginSustain, endSustain, endRamp, hue, sat, lum)
{
    var id25432 = charIDToTypeID( "HStr" );
    var desc1114 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id25433 = charIDToTypeID( "Clrz" );
    desc1114.putBoolean( id25433, false );
    var id25434 = charIDToTypeID( "Adjs" );
    var list89 = new ActionList();
    var desc1115 = new ActionDescriptor();

    var id25435 = charIDToTypeID( "LclR" ); //local range
    desc1115.putInteger( id25435, localRange );
    var id25436 = charIDToTypeID( "BgnR" ); //begin ramp
    desc1115.putInteger( id25436, beginRamp );
    var id25437 = charIDToTypeID( "BgnS" ); //begin sustain
    desc1115.putInteger( id25437, beginSustain );
    var id25438 = charIDToTypeID( "EndS" ); //end sustain
    desc1115.putInteger( id25438, endSustain);
    var id25439 = charIDToTypeID( "EndR" ); //end ramp
    desc1115.putInteger( id25439, endRamp );

    //hue
    var id25440 = charIDToTypeID( "H   " );
    desc1115.putInteger( id25440, hue );

    //saturation
    var id25441 = charIDToTypeID( "Strt" );
    desc1115.putInteger( id25441, sat );

    //light
    var id25442 = charIDToTypeID( "Lght" );
    desc1115.putInteger( id25442, lum );

    var id25443 = charIDToTypeID( "Hst2" );
    list89.putObject( id25443, desc1115 );
    desc1114.putList( id25434, list89 );
    executeAction( id25432, desc1114, DialogModes.NO );
}

// example (localRange, beginRamp, beginSustain, endSustain, endRamp, hue, sat, lum)
//colourhsl(3,75,105,135,165,0,-100,0);
```